# Can't Figure out #Error on Form Footer in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a data entry form that I set up in MS Access.  It is a continuous form, and has a footer which accumulates field totals.

I set up my totals with the `=sum([fieldname])` in the Control Source property and it was working, but for some odd reason it stopped working and all I get now are `#Errors`.

I've double-checked the Syntax and spelling and don't see any issues.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this error?

Comment: Does `fieldname` contain null values for some records?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to abandon this project.  I'm sorry for any inconvenience I have caused anyone.